# Cumulative distribution function of Y

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance, cumulative-distribution-functions

How do you get the cumulative distribution function of $Y$ in terms of $X$?

Let's say that $E[X] = μ, Var[X] = σ^2,$ and $Y =a + bX$.

What would be the process to get the cumulative distribution function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let's say that $E[X] = μ, Var[X] = σ^2,$ and $Y =a + bX$.
>
> Wouldn't $E[Y]$ = $a + Bμ$ and $Var[Y] = B^2 σ^2$?

It actually would be that.

> What would be the process to get the cumulative distribution function?

You start with the cummulative distribution function for $X$.

If $F_{\small X}(x)$ is the CDF for $X$, and $b>0$, then $F_{\small Y}(y)$, the cdf for $Y$, is:$$F_{\small Y}(y) ~=~ F_{\small X}\left(\dfrac{y-a}b\right)$$

Since $\mathsf P(Y\leqslant y) ~{= \mathsf P(a+bX\leqslant y)\\=\mathsf P\left(X\leqslant (y-a)/b\right)}$

Comment: I understand. Thank you!